# Set Caret Position in 'contenteditable' div that has children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">This is some plain, boring content.</div>
```

I also have this function that allows me to set the caret position to anywhere I want within the div:

```
// Move caret to a specific point in a DOM element
function SetCaretPosition(object, pos)
{
    // Get key data
    var el = object.get(0); // Strip inner object from jQuery object
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();

    // Set the range of the DOM element
    range.setStart(el.childNodes[0], pos);
    range.collapse(true);

    // Set the selection point
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

This code works completely fine until I start adding child tags `(span, b, i, u, strike, sup, sub)` to the div e.g.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    This is some <span class="fancy">plain</span>, boring content.
</div>
```

Things get more complicated when these child tags end up with child tags of their own e.g.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    This is some <span class="fancy"><i>plain</i></span>, boring content.
</div>
```

Essentially, what happens, is that `setStart` throws an `IndexSizeError` when I try to `SetCaretPosition` to an index higher than the start of a child tag. `setStart` only works until it reaches the first child tag.

What I need, is for the `SetCaretPosition` function to handle an unknown number of these child tags (and potentially an unknown number of nested child tags) so that setting the position works in the same way it would if there were no tags.

So for both this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">This is some plain, boring content.</div>
```

and this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    This is <u>some</u> <span class="fancy"><i>plain</i></span>, boring content.
</div>
```

`SetCaretPosition(div, 20);` would place the caret before the 'b' in 'boring'.

What is the code I need? Many thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So, I was experiencing the same issue and decided to write my own routine quickly, it walks through all the child nodes recursively and set the position.
Note how this takes a DOM node as argument, not a jquery object as your original post does

```
// Move caret to a specific point in a DOM element
function SetCaretPosition(el, pos){

    // Loop through all child nodes
    for(var node of el.childNodes){
        if(node.nodeType == 3){ // we have a text node
            if(node.length >= pos){
                // finally add our range
                var range = document.createRange(),
                    sel = window.getSelection();
                range.setStart(node,pos);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
                return -1; // we are done
            }else{
                pos -= node.length;
            }
        }else{
            pos = SetCaretPosition(node,pos);
            if(pos == -1){
                return -1; // no need to finish the for loop
            }
        }
    }
    return pos; // needed because of recursion stuff
}
```

I hope this'll help you!

Comment: Thanks! I ended up writing a function of my own that preserves the jQuery object and recursively searches DOM children, but this is also useful!

Comment: I have been searching the internet all week and I haven't found a single answer that works better than this one

Comment: > I hope this'll help you!
It sure did! Thank you so much @Sorunome.

Comment: It would have taken me ages to work this out.  Thank you!

Comment: Nearly eight years later, this answer is the perfect fit for my need right now. Thank you, [@Sorunome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2014411/sorunome), for taking the time to post it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to position the caret based on the character index of the content editable, the easiest way would be using `modify` method:

```js
const position = 6;

const el = document.querySelector('#editable');
const selection = document.getSelection();

if (!selection || !el) return;

// Set the caret to the beggining
selection.collapse(el, 0);

// Move the caret to the position
for (let index = 0; index < position; index++) {
  selection.modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
}
```

No need to traverse the child nodes.

Answer (score -1):

It only work for **object Text** childNodes(0).So you have to make it.Here is not so very standard code,but works.Goal is that (p) id of (we) will output object text.If it does then it might work.

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<p>dd</p>psss<p>dd</p><p>dd</p>
<p>text text text</p>
 </div>
<p id='we'></p>
<button onclick="set_mouse()">focus</button>
 <script>
function set_mouse() {
    var as = document.getElementById("editable");
    el=as.childNodes[1].childNodes[0];//goal is to get ('we') id to write (object Text)
  var range = document.createRange();
     var sel = window.getSelection();
range.setStart(el, 1);
range.collapse(true);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);

document.getElementById("we").innerHTML=el;// see out put of we id
}
</script>
```