# How do I set the caret position inside a contenteditable div that contains other elements within?

Tags: javascript, range, position, caret

I need a script to place the caret of a `contenteditable div` right after the last character typed.

Simply typing a character doesn't work, since I have other scripts dealing with CJK character convertion, changing the div's `innerHTML` at each `onInput` event (and thus, resetting the caret position every time).

I am using the code in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736680/#answer-16737647) to get the current position of the caret, inside the `contenteditable div`.

I am storing the caret position generated from the code above in the browser's `localStorage`.

Whenever I need to set the caret position at the desired place, I call the following function , where `pos` is the value stored + 1:

```
  function setCursor(pos) {
    var tag = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
    var setpos = document.createRange();
    var set = window.getSelection();
    setpos.setStart(tag.childNodes[0], pos);
    setpos.collapse(true);
    set.removeAllRanges();
    set.addRange(setpos);
    tag.focus();
  }
```

Everything works fine for all the text inside the div up until its first child. From there onwards, it no longer works, and I get the following error in the console:

`Uncaught DOMException: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount`

I also tried changing my `function showCaretPos()` for the `function SetCaretPosition(el, pos)` in [this other similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869503/#answer-36953852). But, again, it stops working from the first child onwards, this time, with the error `InternalError: too much recursion`.

How can I fix this, having it work regardless of the existance of children elements?

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/dL86jp2o/1/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Caret Position in 'contenteditable' div that has children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869503/set-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div-that-has-children)

Comment: Not really. I tried replacing my `setCursor(pos)` function for the `SetCaretPosition(el, pos)` in the answer you mentioned. I get the error `InternalError: too much recursion`.

Comment: @Recap Karadas It works as fine as the code I currently have. Which means it breaks at the first child, working fine until there.

Comment: Actually I didn't add an answer, because I tested my mentioned answer before I flagged your question as duplicate. Here is the fiddle that works perfectly imho [http://jsfiddle.net/4j5y6p0g/](http://jsfiddle.net/4j5y6p0g/) (Comments begin with "RK:").